# Clamp & articulating arm suggest for overhead photography rig

Tags: product-photography, food-photography

I’m in the process of building an overhead photography rig for food photography

I’ve got a single horizontal metal bar going across the long length of the table with the idea of clamping something similar to this on it with my camera hanging down. The problem I’m having is that I’m unable to find anyone who sells something similar to this Neewwer articulating arm which would take the weight/work with a ballhead, Nikon camera + lens (around 1.5kg total)

Does anyone have any other suggestions or know a brand which does this?

[image]

Comment: Are you intending on mounting the camera to the clamp arm through the hot shoe?

Answer (score 5):

The Manfroto “Magic Arm” should work for you. It is much larger version of what you have shown, and it can handle loads up to about 6 lbs.

Each arm is about 10” long, and it is very easy to attach a Super Clamp or Quick Release Clamp to either end.

[Manfroto Magic Arm](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=Magic%20arm&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top%20Nav-Search=)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Apart from the specific product name, is there a specific, general term for this kind of equipment?

Comment: “Articulating Arm” is probably correct but “Magic Arm” is widely used by other sellers as well.

Comment: A little heavier duty. There are also cheaper off brand versions available.  Search for 'articulated arm'. https://www.amazon.ca/Manfrotto-Section-Double-Articulated-Bracket/dp/B000MWWXJ2/ref=sr_1_20?ie=UTF8&qid=1546887897&sr=8-20&keywords=articulated+arm